# Why don't we have a browsable spacetime augmented virtual solar system?

Tags: solar-system

Wouldn't it be nice to be able to render any viewpoint from all the data transformed into a point cloud, an augmented virtual reality of moving objects in our solar system.

I would just like to be able to chose any point in the solar system and view exactly what is there at a specific time.

It's possible to extrapolate 3D data from multiple viewpoints of an object, don't we have enough satellite data to do it?

Comment: Are you asking why nobody has developed one yet?

Comment: i was hoping someone could tell me its been done, browsing individual satellite data (limited public access, hard to find) one image at a time is not very practical and limited by vantage point and search capability of source

Comment: So you want to see what stars, planets, nebulae (deep sky objects), 
moons, asteroids, comets, spacecraft (including artifical satellites) 
are visible from a given location inside or outside our galaxy, 
including from any point in our solar system? Also, are you currently 
getting satellite data from 
http://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/master.asp or similar?

Answer (score 2):

There is NASA/JPL's [Solar System Simulator](http://space.jpl.nasa.gov/). It doesn't cover all points, but does include many of the interesting ones.

Comment: im looking for a simulation that is reality augmented, sort of HDR for 3d spacetime data

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but can't [Celestia](http://www.shatters.net/celestia/) do what you want?

Comment: im interested in near small objects and real vantage points

Comment: Why are the vantage points of Celestia not "real"?
There are, by the way, large amounts of extra data that can be downloaded as add-ons for Celestia.

Comment: you wont find all the object that might be in your vantage point in reality in celestia

Comment: We've yet to find all the near earth asteroids, far less take pics of them that look like anything beyond dim points of light.

Comment: OK, I understand what it is that you want now. Since I have put up another answer with a better suggestion, I think I will delete this answer unless anyone protests.

Answer (score 0):

Hayden Planetarium / AMNH's [Digital Universe](http://www.amnh.org/our-research/hayden-planetarium/digital-universe) might be what you are looking for. However, the free version does not include the solar system, only Milky Way stars and extragalactic objects. If if somehow you could get or create the Solar data, it can definitely show them. It is not super user friendly though, but it can do some pretty impressive things. So... It exists. But it is not free, and I am not even sure it is available if you are not a Planetarium.